# what is the best practice using async method in lock

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, locking

In .Net Core,many I/O methods have async version,and Microsoft suggests us to use them for better performance.

But as we know,async methods can't work right in normal lock,because normal lock is relative to thread.

For example，Using ReadWriteLocker in MemoryCache.when MemoryCache is missing，I need read data from database.
I have known 2 ways to solve this problem now:

1. convert async database query method to sync,such as "Wait" or ".Result".
2. using special lock, such as redis lock or some unofficial AsyncReaderWriteLocker.(I have found one,but I haven't read its code yet,so I don't know the detail,the cost or new bug about it)

So back to title,when I have to use async method in lock,what is the best way?I need some suggestions.
Thanks a lot for reading my poor English.

Comment: You can use a [SemaphoreSlim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8), which has a [WaitAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=netframework-4.8) method

Comment: I know how to use SemaphoreSlim  instead of  simple lock ,but instead of ReadWriteLocker is hard.

Comment: Yes, there's no built-in async read/write lock unfortunately.

Comment: We've been using `AsyncReaderWriterLock` from [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncEx` library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) with great success.

Comment: Thank you for answer，I will read the AsyncReaderWriteLocker‘s code.But I wonder if there is a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Tanks a lot. I will study this code.

Answer (score 6):

`lock` is just syntactic sugar for a Monitor, which only allows one thread in at a time, hence why it cannot be used with async/await.

A Semaphore, on the other hand, can coordinate access to shared resources between multiple threads safely.  You can do what you need with `SemaphoreSlim`, like this.  First declare a semaphore in a field or a property that is accessible from wherever you need the thread protection:

```
public readonly SemaphoreSlim _mySemaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
```

Then use it like this:

```
await _mySemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
// Do whatever other sync or async operations you need.
_mySemaphoreSlim.Release();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer,I have known SemaphoreSlim's basic usage，but when I need a ReadWriteLocker，using SemaphoreSlim to write an AsyncReadWriteLocker is  hard。so I wonder if there is a better way to solve the problem。

Comment: Do you have any documentation that it's syntactic sugar for a semaphore? As far as I know it's actually syntactic sugar for the `Monitor` class, which uses some extra memory allocated to all references types for the lock management.